# Mac OS X: Open file in finder + App Sandbox

Tags: macos, sandbox, entitlements, appstore-sandbox

I try to open a finder window  which works fine but every time I do this there is 1 second delay and an error logged.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] selectFile:@"Users/[TheUser]/Downloads" inFileViewerRootedAtPath:pathStr];
```

The log displays:

> __CFPasteboardIssueSandboxExtensionForPath: error for
>   [/Users/TheUser/Downloads/]

Is this normal? I have enabled entitlements and allowed Downloads folder access.

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you solve it ??

Comment: I also have been seeing this, and would like to know the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A bit late, but I just stumbled over this as well and found an answer for this. For this warning/error/whatever it is to disappear, you need to have a security scoped URL to the path (and thats the point where it might be tricky for you, because to obtain such an URL, you *must* use an `NSOpenPanel` and annoy the use, even though you have the right entitlement for the folder!).

Once you have that security scoped URL, you have to call the `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` method and afterwards make your call to `NSWorkSpace`. Don't forget to call `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` afterwards (you can do it immediately after the `selectFile:inFileViewerRootedAtPath:` returned) to free up kernel resources and avoid being unable to make more calls to `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource`.